# Browser add-on to get a POST button's equivalent curl command without having to click first

Tags: web-browser, http

Let's say I have a web page with this POST button:

```
<form method="post" action="somequery">
  [some parameters]
  <button type="submit"> Push me </button>
</form>
```

... and I want to get the [curl command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) that produces the exact same request (including all headers) as if I pushed that button.

Firefox's [Copy as cURL](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/08/firebug-1-12-new-features/#copyAsCURL) allows me to get the equivalent curl command, but only after I have clicked the button/link (same problem with Chrome's [Copy as cURL](https://coderwall.com/p/-fdgoq/chrome-developer-tools-adds-copy-as-curl)). I can't click the button because I am testing software and clicking that button twice would result in the test not being valid.

Should work on either Firefox/Chromium/Chrome/Opera. Gratis.